# Sum of two columns of a table without displaying NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to sum two columns of a table but without displaying NULL. This is what I wrote

```
SELECT (sal+comm) AS [revenue total] FROM pilote
```

But when one of the columns have the NULL, also in the new column 'revenue total' display NULL, even if there's a value in the `sal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ISNULL(sal,0) + ISNULL(comm,0) AS [revenue total] FROM pilote
```